# Problems installing on Pentium 4

Tags: installation

I'm trying to load Ubuntu onto an old pentium 4 pc. The boot disk is good. I've checked the memory and all is OK. I run from the boot disk fine. Get the menu and select install and then I sit and look at a purple screen with 12.04.04 and 4 dots changing colour in its centre for hours. I never get to the 'prepare disk' options tab. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you give some extra detail, RAM, Architecture, and Ubuntu version. It would help others to help you.

Comment: Turned of acpi during boot?

Answer (score 0):

if you use liveCD, then probably would be a problem, so have you ever tried to use usb boot? that is best to work one.